# Re-use Sitemesh layout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles, sitemesh

I have a few webapps that I want to reuse an identical layout for.  I was hoping I could bootstrap the layout via dependency consumption with the simplest method being:

```
<sitemesh>
    <property name="decorators-file" value="classpath:path/to/decorators.xml"/>
    <excludes file="${decorators-file}"/>
```

But that throws an exception.

I guess another option is to have some build trickery to copy the resources to the WEB-INF folder, but that seems like a hack.

I'd prefer some sort of Spring solution (I'm using SpringMVC). I wish Spring had some sort of namespace config so that I could essentially embed the sitemesh.xml and/or decorators.xml.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?  Does Tiles have something like this?

Comment: What exception did you get? a stack trace is always useful.

Comment: How are you building? Typically all your sitemesh stuff is copied to the war so it self-contained.